# How Can I Calculate the Average of Floats in a Nested Array in a Variant Column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a VARIANT column that contains a JSON response from a web service. It contains a nested array with a float value that I would like to aggregate and return as an average. Here is an example SnowSQL command that I am using:

```
select 
value:disambiguated.id,
value:mentions 
from TABLE(
    FLATTEN(input => 
                   PARSE_JSON('{    "entities": [{"count": 2,"disambiguated": {"id": 123},"label": "Coronavirus Disease 2019","mentions": [{"confidence": 0.5928,}, {"confidence": 0.5445,}],"type": "MEDICAL"}]}'):entities
                 )
)
```

Which returns:

```
VALUE:DISAMBIGUATED.ID  VALUE:MENTIONS
123                     [    {      "confidence": 0.5928    },    {      "confidence": 0.5445    }  ]
```

What I would like to return is something with the two "confidence" values averaged to 0.56825. I was able to add a second [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) statement which isolated the "mentions" array and allowed me to extract each "confidence" value. I can not seem to figure out how to group the records to calculate the average. Would love to use the built in [AVG()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/avg.html) function if possible. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, you can use LATERAL FLATTEN to create your required flattened fields, and then aggregate as you normally would.  In this example, I'm grouping on the ID that is in the data, but you could also use `y.index` or `z.index` depending on which of those you wanted to group on for your `AVG()`.

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT PARSE_JSON('{    "entities": [{"count": 2,"disambiguated": {"id": 123},"label": "Coronavirus Disease 2019","mentions": [{"confidence": 0.5928,}, {"confidence": 0.5445,}],"type": "MEDICAL"}]}') as json_str
)
SELECT
y.value:disambiguated.id as id,
avg(z.value:confidence)
from x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => json_str:entities) y,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input => y.value:mentions) z
GROUP BY id
;
```

Comment: This worked! I was able to extended for a more complicated query. It acts just like a GROUP BY and supports the aggregate functions.